# How do I add a mock session for express-session when using SuperTest?

Tags: node.js, express-session, supertest

I have the following session setup...

```
setupSession(){
  const session = {
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    cookie: {},
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  };
  this.app.use(expressSession(session));
}
```

I have the following test...

```
it("User should pass", (done)=>{
  supertest(app)
    .get("/user")
    .set('Cookie', ['connect.sid=...'])
    .expect(200)
    .end(function(err, res){
      if (err) done(err);
      done();
    });
})
```

I now need to mock out a session in the app to make sure that the login is valid? How do I mock a session in the session store so it thinks it is logged in during supertests?

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to accept this, however, my workaround was to wrap the existing Express App in a Test Wrapper that overrode the properties needed for Auth. Like this...

```
const mockAuth = (app)=>{
  const parentApp = express();
  parentApp.use(function(req, res, next) { // lets stub session middleware
    req.isAuthenticated = ()=>true;
    next();
  });
  parentApp.use(app);
  return parentApp;
};
```